How to update a dynamic riverpod UI after configuration changed?
How to update a dynamic riverpod UI after configuration changed?
It feels like bad style to tie the viewmodels to a specific configuration backend which may change in the future. So there should probably be an adapter layer and the viewmodel kept free of details about the configuration backend.
How to feed back changes made in the UI to the configuration backend?
Should the configuration adapter act as a provider to the viewmodel and watch the viewmodel state at the same time?
Thank you for useful answers ...
